# Applying a method to a column in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset imported via Pandas that has a column full of arrays with strings in them, i.e.:

```
    'Entry'
0   ['test', 'test1', test2']
.
.
.
[n] ['test', 'test1n', 'test2n']
```

What I would like to do is apply a function to ensure that there are no similar elements in the array. My method is as follows:

```
def remove_duplicates ( test_id_list ):
    new_test_ids = []
    for tags in test_id_list:
        if tags not in new_test_ids:
            new_test_ids.append(tags)
    return new_test_ids
```

I want to apply this to the 'Entry' column in my DataFrame via either `apply()` or `maps()` to clean up each column entry. I am doing this via

`training_data['Entry'].apply(remove_duplicates(training_data['Entry']))`

But I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    training_data['Entry'].apply(remove_duplicates(training_data['Entry']))
  File "/home/~~~~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2294, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1207, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:66124)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

If anybody can help point me in the right direction, that would be wonderful! I am a bit lost at this point/new to using Pandas for data manipulation.

Comment: `training_data['Entry'].apply(remove_duplicates)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decompose your expression a bit you can see what's wrong.

```
training_data['Entry'].apply(remove_duplicates(training_data['Entry']))
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
x = remove_duplicates(training_data['Entry'])
training_data['Entry'].apply(x)
```

`x` is a list because that's what your `remove_duplicates` function returns. The apply method wants a *function* as Rauch points out, so you'd want `x` to simply be `remove_duplicates`

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

```
df
Out[1190]: 
                    Entry
0     [test, test, test2]
1  [test, test1n, test2n]
```

To make your code work, you can just do:

```
df.Entry.apply(func=remove_duplicates)
Out[1189]: 
0             [test, test2]
1    [test, test1n, test2n]
Name: Entry, dtype: object
```

**You can actually do this without a custom function in a one liner:**

```
df.Entry.apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
Out[1193]: 
0             [test, test2]
1    [test, test2n, test1n]
Name: Entry, dtype: object
```